# What is the correct format for SSRS datetime parameter on Subscription page

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report which takes two dates as parameters. This is meant to be automated report, send regularly via subscription to certain users. Let's say I want dateTo to be today and date from to be today -  days.. I can't figure out the format or formula that would do this in these fields... I am getting :

```
One or more report parameters have an invalid parameter value.
```

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you put those defaults in the report instead of in the subscription?

Comment: I want to submit this report on weekly and also monthly basis, weekly containing data for last 7 days, monthly from the start of the current month... Is this posible inside the report?

Comment: You could make another parameter like @ReportPeriod, that accepts either "Daily", "Weekly" or "Monthly", and the subscription sets the value of that.   Then hide the Date parameters and set them inside the report based on the ReportPeriod chosen.

Comment: Just trying that and it looks like the best option... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another parameter like @ReportPeriod, that accepts either "Daily", "Weekly" or "Monthly", and the subscription sets the value of that. Then hide the Date parameters and set them inside the report based on the ReportPeriod chosen.